# An image disappears when the document is put online

Tags: html, css, image

I don't really know how to explain what is happening. I have an image in my website that is normally showing when I'm editing my html and opening it through chrome (basically when it's not already online!). When I upload the document online the image is not showing anymore. I checked the folder and the connection, but it appears to be okay. Also, other elements from the same folder are working properly. Could you please help me?

this is the code:

```
  <div id="purpleSection" class="row bg-purple fullScreen">

            <div class="col-9 offset-3 d-flex align-items-center">
                <p class="display-4 mr-2 line-height">Mi chiamo Giulia Giordano e vengo da Palermo. Attualmente sto
                    frequentando l’ultimo anno dell’Accademia di Belle Arti. Sono una graphic designer, mi occupo di visual
                    communication, design per l’editoria e videografica. Clicca per saperne di più! </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row bg-purple">
            <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-end mb-5">
                <a href="chisono.html" class="mr-5 mt-auto ">
                    <img src="scopridipiu/scopridipiù.png" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Likely a path issue, but we can't really help knowing as little as we do about your situation. Is the image in a folder called `scopridipiu` at the same location as the HTML document? What browser console errors do you see?

Comment: Where can I see my browser console errors? Btw yes, the html document and the scopridipiu folder are inside the same folder!

Comment: You need to research and understand basic use of your browser's developer tools. I can't imagine anyone doing website work without knowledge of that.

Comment: It might be as simple as a missing `/` Try `<img src="/scopridipiu/scopridipiù.png" alt="">`

Comment: Sorry, but you don't have to be rude. I'm writing in another language and I'm also a student beginner. It takes time to learn things. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You don't need to interpret that as rude. It was a fair and honest suggestion. It's really step 1 in web development. Look into your console and your document inspector. I don't know what browser you use, so I can't offer links.

Comment: @DanMullin thanks for your help, but It's not working!

Comment: I'm using google chrome.

Comment: My only other thought is that somehow the `ù` character might be an issue. Can you duplicate the file an name it `scopridipiu.png` to test that out?

Comment: Then hit F12. What do you see under the console tab after a page refresh?

Comment: @DanMullin it worked!! thank you so much, it was the stupidest thing!

Comment: Awesome! Hey, sometimes it's something simple. Glad it works now.

Comment: @isherwood thank you also for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You are never closing your `img` tag, see if closing it helps by adding `</img>` or `/>`

Also it might be an encoding issue. In this row.

```
<img src="scopridipiu/scopridipiù.png" alt=""></img>
```

Try changing your png file to something like `scopridipiu.png` instead of `scopridipiù.png`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it's not working unfortunately!